# Get contacts which have same phone number stored in phone number list in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first time trying Firestore. I have a collection named `users`, where every user is a UID and every user has fields (name, phone, and contacts (array)). I want to get all users where any of the numbers stored in the user's contacts field exists in their phone field. I have tried to learn from documentation but that's too advanced for me right now.

I am using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose for writing the Android app.

```
collection(users)
   ->documents (all users for eg: sd3f3fvv3ac)
       - name:""
       - phone:1234
       - contacts: array(all phone numbers)
```

So I want all those users/documents whose phone number is in the contacts array of the current document/user I am referring to.

I want something similar to this we might have done in SQL.

```
select * from users where phone IN (select contacts from users where user_id = {current user})
```

.
[this is a screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJVqR.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've updated. Please check

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo ive updated again

Comment: To understand better, do you need to get only the users that have their phone number present in the `contacts` array?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, thats what I want

Answer (score 0):

```
val citiesRef = db.collection("users")

citiesRef.whereArrayContains("contacts", phone).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
             //read data
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                //erormessage
            }
    }
```

With this code, the contacts that are the same as the phone number you wrote in the phone section are listed.

Comment: No its not what i want. check the updated question. phone number field is unique to each document however its possible. that contact array might contain other user's phone number and i want all users whose phone number is there.

Comment: Have you tried the code and it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get only the users that have their phone number present in the `contacts` array in a single go. So you have to query the `users` collection twice, once to get the phone number, and second to verify if that number is present in the array. So the following lines of code will do the trick:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val usersRef = db.collection("users")
usersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { usersTask ->
    if (usersTask.isSuccessful) {
        for (userDoc in usersTask.result) {
            val phone = userDoc.getString("phone")
            phone?.let {
                usersRef.whereArrayContains("contacts", phone).get().addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        for (doc in it.result) {
                            val name = doc.getString("name")
                            Log.d(TAG,"$name")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be the name of all users who have their phone number added to the `contacts` array.

P.S.

I've seen that you're trying to use Jetpack Compose for building your app, a case in which I recommend your read the following article where I have explained how you can do that in clean architecture:

- [How to display data from Firestore using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-49ee736dc07d)

Comment: Hey Prabhjot. Have you tried the solution in my answer? Does it work?